# Editing axis and plot style in Tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot

I finally got tikzpicture and gnuplot to work directly in TeXstudio. Now I want to create a plot by fitting a curve to some data.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{miktex}{gnuplottex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=-16, xmax=16, ymin=0, ymax=600, xlabel={$x$ in mm}, ylabel={$N$}]
        \addplot gnuplot [raw gnuplot]{
            unset key;
            set xrange [-16:16];
            f(x) = A/sqrt(2*pi*o**2)*exp(-(x-xc)**2/(2*o**2))+B;
            A = 500;
            fit g(x) "data.dat" via A, o, xc, B;
            plot "data.dat" with xyerrorbars, f(x);
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Plotting works flawlessly but I want to change the style a bit. It currently looks like this:

[image: bad looking plot]

I want to

- rotate the ylabel
- only show markers for the data, no lines
- change the marker size
- only show lines for the fit
- display "xyerrorbars"

Thanks for your help!

Edit: 
The first two columns are x and y. The third and fourth columns are xerr and yerr.

```
-15 34  0,5 5,83
-10 66  0,5 8,12
-8  87  0,5 9,33
-6  65  0,5 8,06
-5  71  0,5 8,43
-4  97  0,5 9,85
-3  105 0,5 10,2
-2  165 0,5 12,8
-1  389 0,5 19,7
0   553 0,5 23,5
1   501 0,5 22,4
2   288 0,5 17,0
3   146 0,5 12,1
4   84  0,5 9,17
5   90  0,5 9,49
6   75  0,5 8,66
8   89  0,5 9,43
10  73  0,5 8,54
15  35  0,5 5,92
```

Comment: I don't suppose you can add the data file to your question as well? At least a few rows.

Comment: Oh, of course! I forgot to add it.

Comment: Is the third column the x-error and the fourth column the y-error?

Comment: Exactly. The y-error is sqrt(y) if that's of any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I couldn't immediately make the error bars work, I suggest using `gnuplot` only for the fit, and "normal" `pgfplots` for the points with error bars.

This does require a change in your data file though, replacing the commas with periods.

The `filecontents` stuff below is just to make the example self-contained, you don't need it.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
-15 34  0.5 5.83
-10 66  0.5 8.12
-8  87  0.5 9.33
-6  65  0.5 8.06
-5  71  0.5 8.43
-4  97  0.5 9.85
-3  105 0.5 10.2
-2  165 0.5 12.8
-1  389 0.5 19.7
0   553 0.5 23.5
1   501 0.5 22.4
2   288 0.5 17.0
3   146 0.5 12.1
4   84  0.5 9.17
5   90  0.5 9.49
6   75  0.5 8.66
8   89  0.5 9.43
10  73  0.5 8.54
15  35  0.5 5.92
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xmin=-16, xmax=16, ymin=0, ymax=600,
  xlabel={$x$ in mm}, ylabel={$N$},
  ylabel style={rotate=-90},
]

\addplot +[
   only marks,
   mark size=1pt,
   error bars/.cd,
     x dir=both, x explicit,
     y dir=both, y explicit
   ]
   table[
     x index=0,y index=1,
     x error index=2,y error index=3
   ] {data.dat};

\addplot gnuplot [
     mark=none,raw gnuplot
   ]{
            unset key;
            set xrange [-16:16];
            g(x) = A/sqrt(2*pi*o**2)*exp(-(x-xc)**2/(2*o**2))+B;
            A = 500;
            fit g(x) "data.dat" via A, o, xc, B;
            plot g(x);
      };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! By adding "/pgf/number format/read comma as period" to the options in "table[...]" I can use commas instead of periods.

Comment: @Limechime Ah, right. I'd forgotten that was an option.